# Spark Cassandra Connector behaves different from CQL shell - Insert issue

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, apache-spark-sql, cql, spark-cassandra-connector

I have the following Cassandra DM:

```
  CREATE TABLE table (
    id uuid,
    timestamp timestamp STATIC,
    value1 text STATIC,
    value2 int,
    value3 text,
    data map <text,text>,
    PRIMARY KEY ( id, value2 )
);
```

So far so good. Now I have have to types of formats i want to insert first:

```
INSERT INTO table (id, timestamp, value1)
VALUES (<uuid>,<timestamp>,<some-string>);
```

and

```
INSERT INTO table (id, value2, value3, data)
VALUES (<some-id>,<some-int>,<some-string>, <some-simple-json-map>)
```

Both CQL statements work fine.
Now I am developing my spark streaming app getting data and formatting it to dataframes styled like my CQL statements. I get for each set of statement 1 several sets of statement 2.

Now I have the issue when I save my dataframe like the first CQL statement  spark throws a cassandra exception:

```
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 

        Some primary key columns are missing in RDD or have not been selected: value2
            at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.TableWriter$.checkMissingPrimaryKeyColumns(TableWriter.scala:190)
            at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.TableWriter$.checkColumns(TableWriter.scala:257)
            at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.TableWriter$.apply(TableWriter.scala:275)
            at com.datastax.spark.connector.RDDFunctions.saveToCassandra(RDDFunctions.scala:36)
           ...
```

Here the schema of my dataframe:

```
 root
  |-- id: string (nullable = true)
  |-- timestamp: long (nullable = true)
  |-- value1: string (nullable = true)
```

My save statment:

```
 data.select("id", "timeStamp", "value1")
    .write.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
      .mode(SaveMode.Append)
      .options(Map("keyspace" -> "some_keyspace","table" -> "table"))
      .save()
```

When i add the value 2 column to my dataframe the statement works fine.

```
root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- timestamp: long (nullable = true)
 |-- value1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- value2: integer (nullable = false)
```

Is there a way making it work like CQL statement without changeing the Datamodel?

Comment: Looks like a bug with static columns, you should file a Jira

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A static column is a special column that is shared by all the rows of the same partition. In the first insert example, CQL allows you to insert static only data for the partition:

> insert into ctest (id, timestamp, value1) VALUES (233177ff-439b-4a2d-a8b0-4db742b4bc1b, '2013-01-01 00:05+0000', 'one');
>
> select * from ctest;

```
 id                                   | value2 | timestamp                | value1 | data | value3
--------------------------------------+--------+--------------------------+--------+------+--------
 233177ff-439b-4a2d-a8b0-4db742b4bc1b |   null | 2013-01-01 00:05:00+0000 |    one | null |   null
```

This creates a synthetic row; it looks like a row, but it is just a partition key and a static column.  If you insert an real row having a primary key, the null value will disappear:

> insert into ctest (id, value2) VALUES (233177ff-439b-4a2d-a8b0-4db742b4bc1b, 1);
>
> select * from ctest;

```
 id                                   | value2 | timestamp                | value1 | data | value3
--------------------------------------+--------+--------------------------+--------+------+--------
 233177ff-439b-4a2d-a8b0-4db742b4bc1b |      1 | 2013-01-01 00:05:00+0000 |    one | null |   null

(1 rows)
```

Having performed two inserts you only have one row.

The Spark-Cassandra connector is more strict and is not allowing you to insert static only data for a partition.  The connector code checks if all of the columns in the primary key are defined.  It finds two columns in the primary key ( id, value2 ), only one is set and it raises an error.  Below is the check in com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.TableWriter:

```
 private def checkMissingPrimaryKeyColumns(table: TableDef, columnNames: Seq[String]) {
    val primaryKeyColumnNames = table.primaryKey.map(_.columnName)
    val missingPrimaryKeyColumns = primaryKeyColumnNames.toSet -- columnNames
    if (missingPrimaryKeyColumns.nonEmpty)
      throw new IllegalArgumentException(
        s"Some primary key columns are missing in RDD or have not been selected: ${missingPrimaryKeyColumns.mkString(", ")}")
  }
```

For a little more background on this, the book **Learning Apache Cassandra** By Mat Brown discusses static-only inserts on pg 53-54.

Comment: Thanks. That was very helpful.